# My first Sharepoint Hosted App is stuck in "installtion in progress" inside visual studio 2012

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, installation, app

I am working on my first Sharepoint-Hosted APP inside sharepoint server 2013. now i am using Visual Studio 2012, where i did the following steps:-

- create a new sharepoint hosted app.
- specify my team sub-site as the debugging site.
- Build >> Start the new app from visual studio.
- but my app is stuck in the installing status as follow inside visual studio :-

[image]

- and when i went to my sub-site "Site Content" , i got the following :-

[image]

so can anyone adivce what might be causing this ??

Thanks

**----- EDIT -----**

after around half hour , i got these errors/issues inside Visual Studio:-

[image]

and when i click on "Site Contents">>click on the App >> "Details", i got this page:-

[image]

Comment: There should be some ellipses on the top right of the app.  Click that and go to details (or maybe it's about?).  You should be at a page with usage details for the app.  It should include an app installation error count.  If there's any errors, you should be able to click it and see some details.  It's also possible the app is just taking its time and it will install successfully eventually.

Comment: @wjervis thanks for the reply ,, but can you please check my edit to the original question .. seems the installation failed..

Comment: What do you have in your app? It seems there's an issue with an item you have added to your app (required attributes missing).

Comment: @wjervis nothing i just create a sharepoint hosted app,, i did not modify any thing inside it !!

Comment: Did you managed to fixed it if yes then how?